# Force from Johnson Noise

Tags: temperature, capacitance, noise

A capacitor in parallel with a resistor will have a random noise $\mathrm{voltage^2}$ across it of average value $V^2 = k_{B}T/C$. If this is a parallel plate capacitor, you can show that the average attractive force between the plates is $k_{B}T/d$ where '$d$' is the spacing.

Note that this is not the same as the Casimir Effect (which is a quantum effect) -- it is a consequence of the thermal variation in the charges on the plates.

Is this effect significant in the universe between bodies ? Does it have a name ? Is there any practical use or effect ?

Answer (score 1):

One could easily estimate the magnitude of this force for a typical capacitor at room temperature - as expected, it is a very small force that can be neglected.

I am not aware of any special name for this effect, but *thermal fluctuations*. In the context of light bulbs (which are very similar to capacitors) we also speak about *thermal emission* from the cathode - the thermal fluctuations make electrons leave the cathode, and then they become accelerated towards the anode by the applied bias.

The important difference between thermal fluctuations/noise and the effects like the Casimir effect is that the one can nowadays conduct experiments at extremely low temperatures (micro-Kelvins temperatures are somewhat of a routine) where the thermal effects become smaller and smaller, unlike the quantum effects.